# Nec USB 3.0 controller drops connection - Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, usb, pcie, xhci-hcd

I have some serious problems with Technaxx pci-e 302p card. It has uPD720200a NEC chip with 4020 firmware. BIOS recognises it.
Sometimes it recognises devices and system mounts them and are functional for few minutes, other times they can't be mount and error occours.
After fresh install card worked fine, but after kernel and firmware update it behaves as mentioned.

Outputs:

uname -a

```
Linux asd-GA-MA770-UD3 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -vvv

```
USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at fd8fe000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07d1:3c0a D-Link System DWA-140 RangeBooster N Adapter(rev.B2) [Ralink RT3072]
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 1997:1221  
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 15c2:003c SoundGraph Inc.
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          12713  0 
nls_cp437              16991  0 
vfat                   17585  0 
fat                    61512  1 vfat
vesafb                 13844  1 
saa7134_alsa           18602  1 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
bluetooth             180104  10 rfcomm,bnep
tda827x                18182  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  1 
ir_lirc_codec          12859  0 
lirc_dev               19204  1 ir_lirc_codec
tda8290                22616  1 
arc4                   12529  2 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224173  1 
ir_mce_kbd_decoder     12777  0 
ir_sony_decoder        12510  0 
ir_jvc_decoder         12507  0 
tuner                  27428  1 
ir_rc6_decoder         12507  0 
snd_hda_intel          33773  5 
rt2800usb              22684  0 
rt2800lib              58925  1 rt2800usb
crc_ccitt              12667  1 rt2800lib
rt2x00usb              20762  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              51144  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
mac80211              506816  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
ir_rc5_decoder         12507  0 
rc_avermedia_m135a     12526  0 
rc_imon_pad            12505  0 
ir_nec_decoder         12507  0 
cfg80211              205544  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_ctxfi             111202  2 
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
imon                   32839  0 
snd_pcm                97188  5 saa7134_alsa,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_ctxfi
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
saa7134               181851  1 saa7134_alsa
videobuf_dma_sg        19354  2 saa7134_alsa,saa7134
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 17693  0 
rc_core                26412  13 ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_rc5_decoder,rc_avermedia_m135a,rc_imon_pad,ir_nec_decoder,imon,saa7134
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
fglrx                3263886  101 
videobuf_core          26390  2 saa7134,videobuf_dma_sg
v4l2_common            16454  2 tuner,saa7134
videodev               98259  3 tuner,saa7134,v4l2_common
sp5100_tco             13791  0 
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    78855  28 saa7134_alsa,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_ctxfi,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
tveeprom               21249  1 saa7134
i2c_piix4              13301  0 
soundcore              15091  1 snd
edac_core              53746  0 
serio_raw              13211  0 
snd_page_alloc         18529  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_ctxfi,snd_pcm
edac_mce_amd           23709  0 
wmi                    19256  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
parport_pc             32866  1 
k10temp                13166  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
usb_storage            49198  0 
uas                    18180  0 
usbhid                 47199  0 
hid                    99559  1 usbhid
firewire_ohci          41000  0 
firewire_core          63558  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
floppy                 70365  0 
pata_atiixp            13204  2 
r8169                  62099  0
```

dmesg | tail after plugging to usb 3.0 port

```
[  834.871296] sd 9:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  834.871308] sd 9:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  834.871319] sd 9:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  834.871330] sd 9:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  834.871530] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Unhandled error code
[  834.871536] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  834.871545] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 0e 8e 48 0a 00 00 3e 00
[  834.871564] end_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 244205578
[  834.875497] sd 8:0:0:1: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  834.885339] usb 9-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

Are there any other outputs need for answering? I'll post them ASAP.

I could of course reject updating the system but I think it's halfway solution. Any help appreciated.
BTW USB 2.0 and 1.1 ports run well, card itself runs under win7 as charm.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my USB 3.0 card which uses Nec/Renesis controller. My card has two ports and when I connected storage enclosure (WD) to one port I had problems with recognizing it.

What I found - I had to plug some other device into **the second port** to make the first port work. Apparently kernel driver for Nec chips cannot selectively enable/disable individual ports in my card. So I needed to use BOTH ports on that card to make it work correctly.

I just plugged in webcam, but I think any other usb device will do the job. Ports are completely independent (they are seen as separate USB buses in "lsusb -t" output), so if one device is slow, it won't affect transfer speed of another port.